# CouchbaseError: Data received on socket was not in the expected format - couchbase?

Tags: node.js, database, npm, couchbase

we are trying to use the npm couchbase module which is the most basic step:

```
var couchbase = require('couchbase');
var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://127.0.0.1');
var bucket = cluster.openBucket('default');

  bucket.upsert('testdoc', {name:'Frank'}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  bucket.get('testdoc', function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(result.value);
   // {name: Frank} 
 });
});
```

We keep on running into this:

`CouchbaseError: Data received on socket was not in the expected format
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1`

Any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

For the posterity, I faced this issue in two cases:

- bad authentication (so review authentication if any, may not apply in recent versions)
- creating and try to open the bucket immediately afterwards (wait/retry in a few second)

Currently using v5.1.1 CE